# Using "before" as an adverb in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: usage

Can I use the word "before" as an adverb in the beginning of a sentence? And if I can't, what word or a group of words should I use then?

For example,

> **Before**, they used to serve a cherry pie at McDonald's. Now they don't.

Is "in the past" a better option?

Comment: "Used to" means before now. Isn't the adverb redundant? And they never served cherry pie at McDonald's, just some combination of dyes, flavorings, and chemically processes materials that was labeled cherry pie.

Comment: @user105719 - “*Isn't the adverb redundant?*” – You can replace “used to serve” with “served”. That’s not the key point of my question. However, *before* in my example is used to contrast with *now* in the next sentence. So it's not redundant. “*And they never served cherry pie at McDonald's, just some combination of dyes, flavorings, and chemically processes materials that was labeled cherry pie.*” – And I used exactly that label in my example.

Comment: Er, no. "Used to" implies they did once and don't now. The simple past has no necessary implication for the present or future: "They served 'cherry' pie at McDonalds all last year and it's still popular there now." *Before* invites the question "Before what?" if the answer is before some unspecified past time, that's exactly what the past tense conveys. There's nothing grammatically wrong with the placement of the adverb. As a style matter for just the two sentences, it has a referent that hasn't appeared.

Comment: I don't see an exact label in your example, but my comment was just a snarky aside.

Comment: @user105719 - "*I don't see an exact label in your example*" - You really don't see the words "cherry pie" in my example?!

Comment: That's not a label; it's a noun phrase that no one would associate with my snarky description "some combination of dyes,...." What am I missing?

Comment: @user105719 - You are missing the fact that description and a label are two different things. While the description might've never been used in a McDonald's  setting, the noun phrase with which what is described was labeled was used quite often. For example, "Would you like a cherry pie?" - "Yes, I'd like two cherry pies, please"

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't parse "with which what is described was labeled was used." Probably just me, but in any case, I doubt it has any bearing on your original question. So I'm done.

Comment: @user105719 - I'll break it up for you. Here is the description: "some combination of dyes, flavorings, and chemically processes materials". What it describes is a certain kind of combination. And it is exactly that combination that was labeled as "cherry pie". Therefore, the noun phrase "cherry pie" IS a label. And I used exactly that label. In McDonald's, while you would probably never hear the description, you would still hear "cherry pie" quite often. And that's exactly the label that I also used in my question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's better to say, 'In the past'.

> In the past they used to serve a cherry pie at McDonald's. Now they don't.

Sometimes people do say 'Before' by itself in casual conversation and this will be understood. However, it sounds like an incomplete thought. The reason is that it implies a specific time before which McDonald's served the pies, but that time is not given. For instance, you could correctly say

> Before 1990 they served a cherry pie at McDonald's. Now they don't.